# Extension of the Lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My question is the following :

is there a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{T}$ (of subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$) that contains *strictly* the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{L}$ of 
Lebesgue measurable sets (in $\mathbb{R}^n$), and such that there is a measure on $\mathcal{T}$ that extends the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{L}$ ?

I guess not, but I did not find a reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible to construct a translation-invariant strict extension of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Such a construction is sketched in Fremlin, *Measure theory*, Vol 4.I Exercise 442Yc, page 289:

> Show that there is a set $A\subseteq[0,1]$, of Lebesgue
>   outer measure $1$, such that no countable set of translates of $A$
>   covers any set of Lebesgue measure greater than $0$.
>
> *Hint:* Let
>   $\langle F_{\xi}\rangle_{\xi<\frak c}$ run over the uncountable closed
>   subsets of $[0,1]$ with cofinal repetitions (4A3Fa), and enumerate the
>   countable subsets of $\Bbb R$ as $\langle I_{\xi}\rangle_{\xi<\frak c}$.
>   Choose inductively $x_{\xi}$, $x'_{\xi}\in F_{\xi}$ such that
>   $x_{\xi}\notin\bigcup_{\eta,\zeta<\xi}x'_{\eta}-I_{\zeta}$,
>   $x'_{\xi}\notin\bigcup_{\eta,\zeta\le\xi}x_{\eta}+I_{\zeta}$;  set
>   $A=\{x_{\xi}:\xi<\frak c\}$.
>
> Show that we can extend Lebesgue measure
>   on $\Bbb R$ to a translation-invariant measure for which $A$ is
>   negligible.
>
> *Hint:* 417A.

The Lemma in 417A reads

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a semi-finite measure
>   space, and ${\cal A}\subseteq{\cal P}X$ a family of sets such that
>   $\mu_*(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n)=0$ for every sequence $\langle A_n \rangle_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
>   in $\cal A$.   Then there is a measure $\mu'$ on $X$, extending $\mu$,
>   such that
>
> (i) $\mu'A$ is defined and zero for every $A\in\cal A$,
>
> (ii) $\mu'$ is complete if $\mu$ is,
>
> (iii) for
>   every $F$ in the domain $\Sigma'$ of $\mu'$ there is an $E\in\Sigma$
>   such that $\mu'(F \mathbin{\Delta} E)=0$.}
>
> In particular, $\mu$ and $\mu'$ have
>   isomorphic measure algebras, so that $\mu'$ is localizable if $\mu$ is.

Answer (score 11):

In Halmos's book *Measure Theory*, there is a series of exercises in the chapter on extension of measures, showing that for $\sigma$-finite measures (such as Lebesgue measure), one can for each nonmeasurable set extend the measure to a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra containing that set. So the answer is **yes**.

Comment: Yes. Now my answer is *definitely* an overkill. :-)

Comment: @Asaf It's still good to know the boundaries of what is possible.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. What if we ask for the extension to also be translation invariant ?

Comment: I guess you are refering to the Haar theorem, which, as far as I understand, says that there is a unique measure on a fixed $\sigma$-algebra (namely the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). So I fail to see how this result implies uniqueness of the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets (which is what we are looking for here).

Comment: @CyrusK: Oh, right. I forgot about the Borel sets requirement. I'll delete my previous comment...

Comment: @CyrusK: If you had a translation-invariant extension of Lebesgue measure to a $\sigma$-algebra containing the Vitali set (and all its translations), you'd have a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

While definitely an overkill, let me give a partial answer.

In set theory there is a concept known as *large cardinals*, these are assumptions which cannot be proved from the usual axioms of ZFC, and often prove the consistency of ZFC (and therefore make a stronger theory).

One particular large cardinal axiom is the existence of a measure extending the Lebesgue measure, encompassing **all** the subsets of $\mathbb R$. Of course it will not be translation invariant on every set of real numbers, but it does extend the Lebesgue measure as requested.

*Added after Michael's answer:* combined, the answers show that we can prove "slight" increments in measurable sets; but we cannot prove that such extension will measure all sets. Not without additional axioms, anyway.

Of course I must add that if one decides to throw away the axiom of choice it is possible that the every set of reals is already Lebesgue measurable, in which case it will be impossible to extend the measure.

Comment: You have written that if we throw axiom of choice then we can prove existence of a measure on all subsets which is laos translation invariant. Can you please provide the proof ar give some reference to study

Comment: In Royden, if GCH is true then there does not exist a measure function on all subsets of R which is sigma additive and translation invariant. Can you please help me in finding proof of this? and what if we assume GCH to be false, Will there exist such a function

Comment: I never wrote "prove". I said *it is possible*, namely it is consistent that this sort of things happen. As for the second comment, just use the axiom of choice, there are plenty of constructions of this type. Vitali sets, etc. Assuming $\sf GCH$ implies the axiom of choice. Not assuming $\sf GCH$ but assuming choice, same proofs work.

Comment: Oh sorry in second comment I want to write: GCH would imply that there does not exist a measure function on all subsets of R in which length of interval is equal to measure of interval(without translation invariant)

Comment: and I only want to ask(which you already told) that this statement is consistent with theory or not. And can you provide some reference for its consistency.

Comment: There's probably a simpler proof; I can't recall one right now. All I can remember is the proof that such measure would induce a saturated ideal on the continuum, which is impossible if the continuum is small. I think that the answer lies by diagonalizing against all sets and constructing a non-measurable set, but I can't remember such proof of the top of my head, and the one I mention above is quite an overkill.

Comment: I gave references in my answer to your question.

Comment: Got it sorry to post here also