# Is Lebesgue measure the only measure that is locally finite, strictly positive and translation-invariant on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Lebesgue measure on Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally finite, strictly positive and translation-invariant.

Is Lebesgue measure the only such measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The trouble is that strict positivity and local finiteness only concern open and compact sets. Adding translation-invariance will yield a unique measure on the Borel sets (up to a positive multiplicative constant). However, there are many translation-invariant $\sigma$-algebras $\Sigma$ between the Borel sets and the Lebesgue measurable sets, and restriction of Lebesgue measure to $\Sigma$ will yield a measure different from Lebesgue measure. Such a restriction still is locally finite and strictly positive and translation invariant.

Moreover, there are are strict extensions of Lebesgue measure which are translation invariant: see [Extension of the Lebesgue measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209532). Again, these extensions are strictly positive and locally finite.

Thus, the three properties you mention are not enough to ensure uniqueness. Either you need to add [regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure) and completeness or require the measure to be defined exactly on the Borel sets in order to obtain the uniqueness statement up to a multiplicative constant also mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: It's good know that somebody thought this through. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

Up to a multiplicative constant, yes.

See here : [Haar Measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure).

Comment: Note that the definition of Haar measure requires some form of regularity, which should be afforded by the "strictly positive" condition; at least, I think.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: Do you mean "strictly positive" implies "some form of regularity"?

Comment: Probably that any point in the measure space is contained in a set of positive/finite measure.

Comment: @Wong: You are right; I didn't check that. Since the measure is locally finite, some open neighborhood around zero has finite measure; hence by translation all the open neighborhoods has finite measure. All closed neighborhoods too have finite measure. This should perhaps be enough for regularity.