# How much we can extend meaurable sets?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist a $\sigma$-algebra $A \supset M$  (with a measure $m$ defined on it) such that

1. $m(I) = L(I)$ where $I$ is any interval in $\Bbb{R}$ and $L(I)$ means the length of the interval,
2. $m$ is $\sigma$-additive.
3. $m$ is translation invariant,

where $M$ is the set of all measurable sets with respect to Lebesgue outer measure (i.e. the usual class of Lebesgue-measurable sets).

Comment: If you've already developed Lebesgue measure on the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, have you tried showing that it satisfies the desired properties? Or are you asking for $A$ to be strictly finer than $M$?

Comment: @JoshKeneda Yes I have seen the proof that it satisfies all these properties.

Comment: An excellent expository paper on this is: Andrew Michael Bruckner and Jack Gary Ceder, *On improving Lebesgue measure*, **Nordisk Matematisk Tidskrift** 23 #2 (1975), 59-68.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I am not able to find the article. May you please help.

Comment: I don't have time to research and write up an answer now (I'm at work), but this is something I'm sure someone else will answer anyway. I gave the reference because it's not very well know and in my opinion should be better known. Most every university library (in the U.S., at least) has this journal, and it's probably even more readily available in Europe. Unfortunately, I don't have digital access to this journal and I only have an off-print copy of the paper (which is at home). In any event, you should find more than you need by googling the phrase "extending Lebesgue measure".

Comment: A similar question was asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/extension-of-the-lebesgue-measurable-sets

The top answer affirms the existence of such an $A$.

Comment: I had a few moments free just now, so I thought I would look here to see if others have added anything. Also, just now I also noticed that you are in India, so I guess my comments about U.S. and European libraries does not help much! :) If you are **really interested** in this topic, then I can send you a photocopy of the Bruckner/Ceder paper by postal mail. If you want me to send it to you, send me your postal address to my email, which is at my profile. I do not have easy access to a scanner, so photocopy + postal mail is easiest for me.

Comment: @JoshKeneda thanks for reference it cleared a lot of doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was first done by Szpilrajn (1935) and later strengthened to non separable extensions by Kakutani and Kodaira (1950). Ciesielski gives a short proof of the non existence of any maximal such extension [here](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~kcies/Other/ElectronicReprints/21.pdf).

Comment: That was the thing which I was not expected till now. Thanks a lot for such reference.

Comment: The link is now broken :(