# Example of sets that are not measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice

This question is a mixture of several related problems.

1. Is there any concrete examples (the examples that are easy to construct and think about, and of which the construction doesn't include heavy language of set theory) for sets that are not Lebesgue measurable?
2. Without Axiom of Choice, is **the existence of sets that are not Lebesgue measurable** unprovable? If so, how to prove this unprovability?
3. Is there concrete, simple examples of sets that are Lebesgue measurable and are **not** Borel measurable?
4. Is **the class of all Lebesgue Measurable sets** a maximal collection of **subsets of $\mathbb{R}$** on which we can define a nonzero measure?

Comment: Have you looked at the myriad of questions that essentially already asked these before?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Could you please give proofs of the statements, or tell me where to find a proof for each?

Comment: Asaf's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: I don’t feel like this can be closed as a duplicate because I am not sure if there is a question that addresses all of these points, but please use the search bar at the top of the page, or search in google (add “math stack exchange” to the search term)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo It hard to search because there are so many ways to say the same thing. I don't think Question 2 and 4 are too broad or have been asked in a similar way before. As for question 1 and 3, I have explained what I mean  _concrete_. Many construction on internet are very set theoretical, which I don't want.

Comment: @StellaBiderman: Note you can close as multiple-duplicates.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: ok... clearing my comment...

Comment: 1. Probably NO for any notion of "concrete" you can think of. 2. Yes --- see [Solovay's 1970 paper.](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m873-03/solovay.pdf) 3. Yes --- see Becker's 1992 paper [Descriptive set theoretic phenomena in analysis and topology](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-9754-0_1) and [Non-Borel sets without axiom of choice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32720/non-borel-sets-without-axiom-of-choice). 4. See [How much we can extend meaurable sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926392/how-much-we-can-extend-meaurable-sets)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thats very helpful