# Can every content be extended to a content on all sets?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra of sets on $X$, and let $\mu$ be a finite [content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_(measure_theory)) on $(X,\mathcal{A})$. Can $\mu$ be extended to a content on $2^X$ (i.e. on $X$'s power-set)?

---

* As far as I know, the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (and hence the Jordan content on $\mathbb{R}$) can be extended to a content on $2^{\mathbb{R}}$, but can this be done in general?

Comment: It depends on what properties you want "content" to have. See, for example, [How much we can extend meaurable sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926392/how-much-we-can-extend-meaurable-sets) and [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kakutani+Kodaira+extending+Lebesgue+measure).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: All the information that I am interested is contained in my question. I am hoping for an answer of "no" and a counter-example showing a content that cannot be extended to the power-set, or even a non-constructive existential argument that shows that such a non-extendable content must exist in the ordinary mathematics (no arcane set-theoretic axioms).

Comment: The word "content" is used in many ways in mathematical analysis, so NO, it is not true (for me) that all the needed information is contained in your question.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: OK. I've clarified the meaning of 'content'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ell^\infty(X)$ be the Banach space of bounded functions on $X$ equipped with the $\sup$ norm. Let $Y$ be the subspace spanned by the set $\{ \chi_A : A \in \mathcal{A} \}$ where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of $A$.

Notice that a finite content $\mu$ on $(X, \mathcal{A})$ defines a linear functional on $Y$ by integration, which I will denote by $\phi$. That is, for $f \in Y$, $\phi(f) = \int f d \mu$. In particular, this gives us that $\phi$ is bounded since the usual properties of the Lebesgue integral for simple functions are true for integration of simple functions against a finite content.

By the Hahn-Banach Theorem, we can extend $\phi$ to a bounded linear functional $\tilde{\phi}$ on all of $\ell^\infty(X)$. You can then check that $\tilde{\mu}(A) = \tilde{\phi}(\chi_A)$ defines a finite content which extends $\mu$ to the power set of $X$.

Comment: Thanks. 1. What is $\mathcal{A}$? 2. What is this example meant to show? It doesn't seem to be a counter-example to the claim stated in my question, but it doesn't seem to prove it either.

Comment: $\mathcal{A}$ is the same thing it is in your question? This answer shows the existence of an extension of an arbitrary finite content $\mu$ on $\mathcal{A}$ which is $\tilde{\mu}$ in my notation

Comment: I see. Thanks. When you say that $\mu$ defines a linear functional on $Y$ by integration, what kind of integration do you have in mind? Lebesgue integration is defined w.r.t. a measure, not a content.

Comment: Here you don't even need a proper integration theory since I only need to define $\phi$ on the space $Y$ of simple functions for the algebra $\mathcal{A}$. So for this, potentially the simplest thing to do is use the usual Lebesgue construction which will work for our purposes without the assumption of countable additivity.

Comment: I see. In order to use the Hahn-Banach theorem, the linear functional determined by $\mu$ via integration needs to be dominated by a sublinear functional that is defined on the entire space $\ell^{\infty}(X)$. What is this sublinear functional in your example?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise the link I'd provided went to the sublinear functional version of Hahn-Banach. There is a simpler, special case that says that a bounded, linear functional defined on a subspace of a normed vector space can be extended to a bounded linear functional of the same norm on the whole space (take the sublinear functional to be a suitable scalar multiple of the norm). Here the sublinear functional is $\mu(X) \| \cdot \|_\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77165/discussion-between-rhys-steele-and-evan-aad).

Comment: I'm finding the use of the word "integration" to be a bit opaque here.  What you mean is $\phi(\chi_{A}) = \mu(A)$ and then extend linearly to $Y$, is that right?  It might help to clarify this in your post.

Comment: @fourierwho Yes, that is a rephrasing of the definition of the Lebesgue integral which works here...