# Characterization for Caratheodory measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, category-theory, measurable-sets

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra over a set $E$, and $\mu$ be a pre-measure over $\mathcal{A}$. We can define an outer measure $\mu^*$ over $2^E$, and a $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{M}$ over $E$ (by Caratheodory theorem). In fact $\mu^*\mid_{\mathcal{M}}$ is a measure $\mu$. (cf. Real Analysis by Folland P29, 30, 31).

I'm thus wondering whether there is a characterization of $\mathcal{M}$ and $m$. That's to say, is $\mathcal{M}$ the maximal $\sigma-$algebra s.t. there exists a measure $k$ with $k\mid_{\mathcal{A}} = \mu$ with [some property]?

Comment: Repeating my comment at [Is there a non-measurable set that you can add to a sigma-algebra and nevertheless remain consistent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4852100/13130): See the answer (only one at this time) and comments to [Extension of measure to non measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985557/13130). See also [How much we can extend meaurable sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/926392/13130) AND [Extension of the Lebesgue measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209532/13130).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks. Whereas how can we characterize this special measure?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not something I've looked at in many years (probably over 20 years), and never very thoroughly. The references I've mentioned in earlier comments are some that I've known about for a long time, but I haven't looked at them in recent years.