# Lebesgue measure beyond Lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Is it possible to extend the Lebesgue measure as a translation-invariant measure from the Borel sigma-algebra to a sigma-algebra not contained in the Lebesgue sigma-algebra?

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/extension-of-the-lebesgue-measurable-sets).

Comment: Thanks! It's intereseting though that the only reference given for this problem is an exercise in a single textbook, taking into account how natural this question is, and how non-trivial the construction seems to be.