# Extension of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

By this [Carathéodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem), we know how to (uniquely) extend a pre-measure from a ring to a $\sigma$-field $\Sigma\subseteq2^{\Omega}$. So it is always posible to extend it further? From any $\sigma$-field, $\Sigma\subseteq\Gamma\subseteq2^\Omega$?

Also, the [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lebesgue_Measure_Invariant_under_Translations) of "Lebesgue measure is invariant under translation" only proves for Borel-sets. And we know that there are sets that are Lebesgue measurable but not Borel. So is there any counter-examples?

Comment: to your second question, you can approximate lebesgue sets with borel sets to prove lebesgue measure is translation invariant for all lebesgue sets.

Comment: to your first question, you can always extend to the "completion" of a measure. And beyond that, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/extension-of-the-lebesgue-measurable-sets