# Is there a maximal translation-invariant extension of Lebesgue measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/extension-of-the-lebesgue-measurable-sets) shows that there are translation-invariant extensions of Lebesgue measure.

> Are there *maximal* translation-invariant extensions of Lebesgue measure? If so, is there more than one?

To be more precise, let $\mathcal L$ be the sigma-algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$. By the linked post, there exists $A \subset [0,1]$ such that $A \notin \mathcal L$ and there exists a translation-invariant measure $\mu'$ on $\sigma(\mathcal L \cup \{A\})$ that extends the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal L$. My question is:

> Is there a sigma-algebra $\mathcal L' \supset \mathcal L$ and a measure $\mu'$ on $\mathcal L'$ such that $\mu'$ is a translation-invariant extension of Lebesgue measure and if $A \not \in \mathcal L'$, then there is no translation-invariant extension of $\mu'$ to $\sigma(\mathcal L' \cup \{A\})$? If such an $\mathcal L'$ exists, is it unique?

Comment: I got an answer to this question at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382299/is-there-a-maximal-translation-invariant-extension-of-lebesgue-measure/382300#382300).