# Why we extend the Borel sigma algebra to the Lebesgue sigma algebra by including precisely zero measure sets

Tags: real-analysis

In measure theory one extends the Borel sigma algebra to the Lebesgue sigma algebra by including all subsets of sets of measure zero. Why is this needed ? Why not including subsets of the sets of measure 1 or other measure ?

Comment: Because Every Lebesgue measurable set are of the form $B\cup N$ where $B$ is a Borel set and $N$ a nul set.

Comment: Because the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$ generated by all subsets of sets of measure $a$ (for some fixed $a>0$) is the whole set of subset of $\mathbb R$, but Lebesgue measure cannot be extended to it.

Comment: Since you are able to measure a set then it is measurable and we have non-borel sets with measure zero so measurable sets are not just borel

Comment: Thanks. I do not understand exactly. What do you mean by 'the whole set of subset of $\mathbb{R}$' ?

Comment: I forgot an *s*: the set of all subsetS of $\mathbb R$. But I retract the end of that sentence: the Lebesgue measure [cannot be extended to a *translation invariant* measure on all subsets of $\mathbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) but if we drop that contraint, the situation is [more complicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209532).

Comment: I again do not understand why the  sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by all subsets of sets of measure a (for some fixed a>0) is the whole set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, which is the power set. Can you provide a reference or a proof for that claim ? Thanks.

Comment: I have no reference at hand, but let $A\subset\mathbb R$, then $A=\cup_{n\in\mathbb Z}(A\cap[na,(n+1)a])$.